# jQuery -listening ( using 'on') to which element?

Tags: jquery

If I write :

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div>
    <input  type="text" class="xxx"/>
 </div>
 <div>
    <input  type="text" class="yyy"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

question :

when I write: `$(".wrapper").on("click",".yyy",function () {});` :

Does it also listen ( and ignores) the `.xxx` events ?

or is it just listen to the `.wrapper` and filters all `non ".yyy"` elements events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It binds the click event to `.wrapper` and if the target was `.yyy`, it will execute the function. This allows you to remove/replace `.yyy` at any time, via ajax or whatever, and keep the bound event.

Comment: Yes. This is similar to `live()` which binds the event to `document`, which is why that function is so expensive and should be used sparingly.

Comment: Except that it doesnt propagete to the document node - but stops in the  wrapper element....

Comment: Correct. It significantly reduces traversal and improves performance.